# waterline createdAt affecting sort order

Tags: sails.js, waterline

The symptoms I see are that after adding an object then viewing the list ordered by `createdAt: 'desc'`, the new object is at the end of the list but should be at the start of the list. I noticed that the date is shown as e.g. `"Thu Mar 06 2014 10:52:56 GMT+0000 (GMT)"` whereas the other objects have a date like `"2014-03-06T10:52:56.875Z"`.

If I change the line in `dql.js`:

```
  if(self.autoCreatedAt) values.createdAt = new Date();
```

to

```
  var today = new Date();
  if(self.autoCreatedAt) values.createdAt = today.toISOString();
```

then the sort order comes out correctly.

After I restart the server, the values are OK, presumably because the data is read in from disk and converted somewhere.

Am I misunderstanding something in how this works and how I add objects via waterline?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. But only if I served the date field with a date-string.

I solved it by adding the following methods to my model:
They convert the date-string to a date-object before saving it.

```
...
beforeCreate: function(values, cb) {
    if(values.createdAt && typeof value.createdAt === 'string'){
        values.createdAt = new Date(Date.parse(values.createdAt));
    }
    return cb();
},
beforeUpdate: function(values, cb){
    if(values.createdAt && typeof value.createdAt === 'string'){
        values.createdAt = new Date(Date.parse(values.createdAt));
    }
    return cb();
}
...
```